# How can including a simple generated header file with some #defines cause seemingly unrelated link errors?

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja, vcpkg

I am working on a project that requires a modified fork of Irrlicht, which is built using CMake, with vcpkg for dependency management.

Recently I introduced a change that generates a simple header file using `configure_file`.

The template header file `IrrCmakeConfigured.h.in` looks like this:

```
#ifndef __IRR_CMAKE_CONFIGURED_H_INCLUDED__
#define __IRR_CMAKE_CONFIGURED_H_INCLUDED__

#define IRRLICHT_VERSION_MAJOR ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}
#define IRRLICHT_VERSION_MINOR ${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
#define IRRLICHT_VERSION_REVISION ${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}
#define IRRLICHT_VERSION_PRERELEASE "${PROJECT_VERSION_PRERELEASE}"
#define IRRLICHT_SDK_VERSION "${IRRLICHT_VERSION}"

#endif
```

Nothing complicated in there, just some defines. The templated values are all integers except for `IRRLICHT_VERSION_PRERELEASE` and `IRRLICHT_SDK_VERSION`, which are strings.

The generated content of `IrrlichtCmakeConfigured.h` is:

```
#ifndef __IRR_CMAKE_CONFIGURED_H_INCLUDED__
#define __IRR_CMAKE_CONFIGURED_H_INCLUDED__

#define IRRLICHT_VERSION_MAJOR 1
#define IRRLICHT_VERSION_MINOR 9
#define IRRLICHT_VERSION_REVISION 0
#define IRRLICHT_VERSION_PRERELEASE "dev"
#define IRRLICHT_SDK_VERSION "1.9.0-dev"

#endif
```

In `CMakeLists.txt` the header file is generated and included in the build like this:

```
configure_file(
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/IrrCmakeConfigured.h.in
    ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/include/IrrCmakeConfigured.h)

include_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/include)
```

And then the generated file is included from another header file, `IrrCompileConfig.h`, like this:

```
#include "IrrCmakeConfigured.h"
```

That header file is itself included from most other files in the project.

The problem I am having, which is to me inexplicable, is that somehow the simple act of importing `IrrCmakeConfigured.h` causes a bunch of errors linking against OpenGL on mac and Linux:

```
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glDrawArrays'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glPopAttrib'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glPointSize'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glFrontFace'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glLightModeli'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glColorMask'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glAlphaFunc'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glLightf'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glClear'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glDisable'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glViewport'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glFogf'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glTexImage2D'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glClipPlane'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glReadPixels'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glGetTexImage'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glPixelStorei'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glGetError'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glMultMatrixf'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glDepthMask'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glDisableClientState'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glXDestroyWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glTexParameterf'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glGetString'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glColorMaterial'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glEnableClientState'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glDepthFunc'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glXDestroyContext'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glXGetProcAddress'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glBlendFunc'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glXMakeCurrent'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glReadBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glPolygonMode'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glRectf'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glScissor'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glEnable'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glXMakeContextCurrent'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glStencilMask'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glGetIntegerv'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glHint'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glFogi'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glMaterialf'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glDrawElements'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glStencilFunc'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glColorPointer'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glXGetProcAddressARB'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glVertexPointer'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glTexEnvi'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glClearDepth'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glXCreateWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glStencilOp'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glXCreateContext'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glBindTexture'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glXCreateNewContext'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glCullFace'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glDeleteTextures'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glTexParameteri'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glTexEnvf'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glGenTextures'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glIsEnabled'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glXQueryVersion'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glPushAttrib'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glDrawBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glFlush'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glXChooseVisual'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glClearColor'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glCopyTexSubImage2D'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glColor4ub'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glTranslatef'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glXQueryExtension'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glPushMatrix'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glPolygonOffset'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glLoadMatrixf'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glShadeModel'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glTexSubImage2D'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glNormalPointer'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glGetFloatv'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glXGetCurrentDisplay'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glFogfv'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glLightfv'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glLineWidth'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glXSwapBuffers'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glPopMatrix'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glLightModelfv'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glClearStencil'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glTexGeni'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glMaterialfv'
/usr/bin/ld: lib/libEmberdawnIrrlicht.so.1.9.0: undefined reference to `glTexCoordPointer'
```

The obvious conclusion is: maybe something is being compiled conditionally based on the defines in the header file, and the defines themselves are causing the problem, but that is not the case.

If I remove the `#include "IrrCmakeConfigured.h"` and simply copy and paste the contents of `IrrCmakeConfigured.h` in its place, then the code links without problems. In other words, it's not the contents of `IrrCmakeConfigured.h` that is causing the problem. It's the act of including the file itself. The same error happens if I include any other header file generated by CMake, even if it's completely empty.

Whatever is causing this problem, it seems to happen during CMake generation time. If I clear the CMake cache, comment out the `#include "IrrCmakeConfigured.h"`, generate the project, uncomment the line, and then compile, then it compiles and links successfully.

So I have to think that CMake is analysing the file, and does something that I'm not expecting when it sees `#include "IrrCmakeConfigured.h"`, which has the side effect of causing link errors. But I don't have enough knowledge of CMake to have a clue what's going on here.

Does anyone have any pointers as to what I should do to try to debug this?

Here's the first commit that causes the build to fail on Linux and mac: https://github.com/emberdawn-game/emberdawn-irrlicht/commit/9bca69cce9118d7c50839f9b823ec7cf2b54622e

The commit before that built successfully on all platforms: https://github.com/emberdawn-game/emberdawn-irrlicht/commit/8e3a79a0c84b34063ec1ed910d021808ef784593

Answer (score 0):

Oh no. OH NO. I figured it out.

There wasn't enough information in my question for anyone to have been able to answer it, but that's not really surprising. Even having narrowed down which change was causing the problem I hardly knew where to start looking.

Well, it turns out, that since the problem was occurring during the CMake project generation step, the best thing to do was to look at the files that CMake generates. In particular, the cache file CMakeCache.txt.

So, knowing that the project seems to generate correctly with the `#include` directive commented out, I generated projects with and without that directive and then diffed the resulting CMake output trees.

Diffing the cache file made the problem fairly obvious:

```
@@ -273,35 +273,8 @@
 JPEG_LIBRARY_RELEASE:FILEPATH=/home/djc/Code/emberdawn-irrlicht/cmake-build-debug/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/lib/libjpeg.a
 
 //Path to a file.
-OPENGL_EGL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/home/djc/Code/emberdawn-irrlicht/cmake-build-debug/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/include
-
-//Path to a file.
-OPENGL_GLX_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include
-
-//Path to a file.
-OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include
-
-//Path to a file.
 OPENGL_REGISTRY_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=/home/djc/Code/emberdawn-irrlicht/cmake-build-debug/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/include
 
-//Path to a library.
-OPENGL_egl_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
-
-//Path to a library.
-OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
-
-//Path to a library.
-OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-
-//Path to a library.
-OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so
-
-//Path to a library.
-OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
-
-//Path to a file.
-OPENGL_xmesa_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=OPENGL_xmesa_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
-
```

All the OpenGL variables are gone from the "bad" version. What the?

Oh. OH.

It turns out that there is a step in the build that does this:

```
include(CheckSymbolExists)
check_symbol_exists(_IRR_COMPILE_WITH_OPENGL_ "IrrCompileConfig.h" OGL_ENABLED)
```

The resulting `OGL_ENABLED` variable then controls if the build links to OpenGL.

The problem is that `IrrCompileConfig.h` includes `IrrCmakeConfigured.h`, but at the time the `check_symbol_exists` check happens, `IrrCmakeConfigured.h` doesn't exist yet. So `check_symbol_exists` can't process the file, and instead it just **fails silently** and assumes that the file does not define any symbols. And lets the build continue.

At compile time, `IrrCompileConfig.h` has been generated, so `IrrCmakeConfigured.h` parses successfully, and the code is compiled with the OpenGL backend included.

Then at link time, CMake has already determined that OpenGL support is turned off, so it doesn't link against OpenGL. And the linker fails.

Argh. Easy to fix now I know what the problem is. I was planning on removing those `check_symbol_exists` anyway in favour of CMake options, I just hadn't got that far yet.